# Deleting objects stored in std::vector

Tags: c++, iterator, stdvector

Just a quick small question :

```
#define SAFE_DELETE(p)    if((p))  { delete(p);    (p) =NULL; }
#define SAFE_DELETE_A(pa) if((pa)) { delete[](pa); (pa)=NULL; }

    // Add objects to our vector
    for(int a = 0; a< 150; a++)
    {
      CObject *pNewObject = new CObjectPlane(...)
      m_vpObjects.push_back(pNewObject);

    }


    // Delete all objects stored in our vector
    std::vector<CObject*>::iterator itObject;
    for(itObject = m_vpObjects.begin(); itObject!=m_vpObjects.end();)
    {
        SAFE_DELETE( (*itObject) );
        itObject = m_vpObjects.erase(itObject);
    }

    m_vpObjects.clear();
```

1) Will that remove objects stored in std::vector ( CObject* )

2) Is it safe to remove them this way ?

Comment: Your SAFE_DELETE() is kind of silly.  C++ guarantees that delete on a NULL pointer is a noop, so there's no need to check first.

Comment: Also I think those #defines aren't a good idea - they may cause some side effects. A bit offtopic, but is it a requirement to use raw pointers instead of some kind of smart pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is safe but potentially (very) slow.

`erase` on the first element of a vector has to move all of the other elements of the vector, so your loop is O(n^2) in the size of the vector.

And there is no need to `erase` the elements since (a) they are pointers (no destructor) and (b) `clear` will do it anyway.

So:

```
for (itObject = m_vpObjects.begin(); itObject!=m_vpObjects.end(); ++itObject)
    SAFE_DELETE( (*itObject) );
```

P.S.  There is nothing particularly "safe" about your `SAFE_DELETE`, but that is another topic.

P.P.S.  `if (p) delete p;` is redundant.

Comment: @PeeS -- Yes.  `clear` has the same effect as erasing all of the elements one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Please do yourself a favor and store smart pointers (e.g. from boost or C++0x) instead of raw pointers inside a vector. This will also relief you from the burden of releasing them safely.

RAII (Resource Acquisition is Initialization) for the win!